# IntelliJ setup with Spark Scala and Sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I am doing spark+Scala+SBT project setup in IntelliJ.

```
    Scala Version: 2.12.8
    SBT  Version:  1.4.2
    Java Version:  1.8
```

Build.sbt file:

```
  name := "Spark_Scala_Sbt"
  version := "0.1"
   scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.3",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.3"
)
```

Scala file:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object FirstSparkApplication extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("Sample App")
    .getOrCreate()
  val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
Seq("I like Spark", "Spark is awesome", "My first Spark job is working now and is counting down these words")
  )
  val filtered = data.filter(line => line.contains("awesome"))
  filtered.collect().foreach(print)
}
```

But its showing below error messages:

```
1. Cannot resolve symbol apache.
2. Cannot resolve symbol SparkSession
3. Cannot resolve symbol sparkContext
4. Cannot resolve symbol filter.
5. Cannot resolve symbol collect.
6. Cannot resolve symbol contains.
```

What should I change here?

Comment: Have you re-built the project before running the project? Have the libraries of Spark been loaded in the External Libraries dropdown tab on the project explorer on the left?

Comment: Are you using [sbt-spark](https://github.com/alonsodomin/sbt-spark) sbt plugin? It allows executing spark program easily...

Comment: @Coursal yes when I m doing rebuild module it's throwing same error.

Comment: @gianluca no I am using intellIiJ and Sbt first time so was following some documents and trying to setup the environment.

Comment: Something may have happened while creating the sbt file structure, can you edit your question so you can add a screenshot of the project explorer on the left, with the External Libraries tab open?

Comment: Hi Coursal I m trying to post image but I m getting error."You need at least 10 reputation to post images" so not able to attach.I am able to see all the jars inside external libraries. Location of main project and build.sbt is same.